# Multiple bulk updates in Python Process

Tags: python, django, django-models, multiprocessing

I am doing bulk updates in 5 tables. It takes a lot of time. So, I decided to do it parallely using python multiprocessing Process object. Here's my code:

```
    def bulk_insert_syllabus_data_parallely(self, data_to_insert):
    syllabus_log.info('inside parallely method')
    # inserts data using multiprocessing
    try:
        processes = []
        for key, value in data_to_insert.iteritems():
            processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=bulk_insert_data, args=(key, value)))

        for p in processes:
            p.start()

        for p in processes:
            p.join()
    except Exception, e:
        syllabus_log.info('Exception=-----%s' % e)

def bulk_insert_data(key, value):
try:
    syllabus_log.info('inside insert data-----%s' % key)
    if key == 'subjects':
        Table1.objects.bulk_create(value)
    elif key == 'chapters':
        Table2.objects.bulk_create(value)
    elif key == 'goals':
        Table3.objects.bulk_create(value)
    elif key == 'los':
        Table4.objects.bulk_create(value)
    elif key == 'tus':
        Table5.objects.bulk_create(value)
    syllabus_log.info('Successfully inserted0------%s' % key)
except Exception, e:
    log.info('Exception-----%s' % e)
    log.info('Exception-----%s' % key)
```

I am getting this exception, only 1 process succeeds. Exception is either SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac or SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected. WHats the issue here and how to resolve it?

Table structure:

```
class TableA(models.Model):
s = models.ForeignKey('S')
s1 = models.ForeignKey('T', related_name='s_s1')
sequence = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
status = models.CharField(default='hidden', max_length=255, db_index=True)
modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: What datatype are your Tables? Can you show us the code for them? The code you have written here does not run, and I do not know how even a single process is able to complete this as the tables are not defined anywhere

In general, you have to feed the table(s) you want to update to your processes as they do not implicitly share memory. Also the tables need to be a thread/process safe data structure

Comment: Added  one table structure. In general I create a list of model objects, ie. data_A = TableA(...). list = list_A.append(data_A). ANd then pass the list to process

Comment: What is models? That doesn't look like a base python class. Are you using some kind of framework? Also where is Table1,Table2,...,Table5 instansiated? I am pretty sure what you want is to send them to the process alongside the key and value as processes do not share memory

Comment: Ohh, its a django ORM. My bad for not providing that info

Comment: Ah I see. Well then I do not think your approach is a good one (unless value is a list of entries). What you are doing is making multiple transactions instead of one, which should be a lot slower and more intensive on the database. You would be much better off making a single process for doing the database transaction and then let your program continue if that is the problem

Comment: Well, its a list of values only. In one table I do one bulk insert only.